# How to sort a pre-selected region

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Every day I run a report, then paste the data into an ongoing Excel spreadsheet. I want to use a macro to sort the data (by color, although that isn't important) so I can choose the records that need to be kept; the rest are deleted.
Each time I do this, the new data is pasted farther down the spreadsheet. The problem is, all the examples of code I can find assume the data to be sorted begins in a known cell. I just want to sort the range that happens to be selected.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub SortByColor2()

Dim rngPasted As Range
Dim SortGreen As String
Dim SortRed As String

Set rngPasted = Selection
SortGreen = "C585"
SortRed = "D585"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(SortGreen), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(SortRed), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Sort
.SetRange rngPasted
.Header = xlNo
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With

End Sub
```

This code works in that it performs the sort. What I need to know is how to set the variables SortGreen and SortRed as 'the first  cell in column C in the selected region' (or D in the case of SortRed) instead of setting its value as a specific cell.
I found a suggestion to use "Selection(3)" but when I tried SortGreen = Selection(3) I got Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.
I have a feeling I'm missing something basic and fundamental here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does your selection begin from Column A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your selection begins from Column A. You can use the `.Cells` Property here:

```vb
Set rngPasted = Selection
SortGreen = Selection.Cells(1, 3).Address
SortRed = Selection.Cells(1, 4).Address
```

If your Selection doesn't begin with Column A (so either B or C), then use the following code (which works in either case, anyway):

```vb
Set rngPasted = Selection
SortGreen = Intersect(Columns(3), Selection.Rows(1)).Address
SortRed = Intersect(Columns(4), Selection.Rows(1)).Address
```

Comment: Should this be `SortGreen = Selection.Cells(1, 3).Address` and so on? Otherwise, SortGreen will contain the value of the cell and that's not guaranteed to make sense when used in `.SortFields.Add(Range(SortGreen),`

Comment: Yes, the selection begins from Column A. Sorry I forgot to make that plain.  Thank you so much! Your suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: @ginevradelcarmine, you are welcome. The second code will work even if your selection doesn't start with A